# iOS Import settings into app from file

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, plist

I know it's possible to make your app open files by changing the info.plist in xcode

Is it possible to have your app open for example a .properties file, which is a plist containing personal user settings i.e. a login username and password, and get your app to read and import this?

Comment: You shouldn't put a password into a plist file. That's could be a security issue.

Comment: You mean open it if it was e-mailed to you or something else?

Comment: Yes it is very possible. You can write/read any plist file even iOS and MAC OSX itself write some app related data by itself in app Sandbox area by UserDefaults but I think Username & Password you shouldn't write in plist because of security reasons.

Comment: @Wain Yes, if it was emailed.

Comment: @SuryakantSharma I agree, however the data isn't confidential and the passwords are randomly generated. The way my app works is it stores the manually entered settings in a plist. Are you saying I can overwrite this?

Comment: manually stores settings means what? I didn't get it. please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Your iOS app can handle some file extension you want to, but take care about the security issue!

Take a look to this tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1980/how-to-import-and-export-app-data-via-email-in-your-ios-app

Answer (score 1):

You can always read a plist file and import them, provided the plist is part of your app's sandbox. If you want to have settings and preferences, you can prefer settings bundle which also is a plist file.

Comment: The way my app works is it stores the manually entered settings in a plist. Are you saying I can overwrite this?

Comment: Yes you can overwrite it.